# Jquery click event for specific link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm using Jquery in Visual Studio ASP.net. I'm trying to display a message everytime someone clicks on a specific image link (class="button notice buttonEight" below) on a page. Here's a snippet of the code from the page:

```
<li class="levelOne"><a class="button notice buttonEight" href="#">
      <img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/PBS-Intranet/_res/_images/icon_notice.png") %>"/></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="endCap">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("icon_notice").click(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually tell jQuery what you're clicking, the computer has no idea what `$("icon_notice")` is.  Add the id `icon_notice` to your image, then select it with `$("#icon_notice")` and that code should work great.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I needed to add an id to the image and now everything works fine!

Comment: Glad to help!  Would you mind marking the question as answered for future Googlers?

Comment: .. which is me :) great!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".notice").click(function() {
   alert("Hello world!");
});
```

Comment: That would work if that was the only tag using the `notice` class.  But if its not it would attach the click event to every tag with the `notice` class.  Using `a.notice` would make it more specific, but could still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your image an Id you can refer to it in jQuery using the id selector notation '$(#<id here>)'.

```
<a class="button notice buttonEight" href="#">
   <img id="icon_notice" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/PBS-Intranet/_res/_images/icon_notice.png") %>" />
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon_notice").click(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    alert("Hello world!");
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're having problems with. You can select your link using any of it's class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buttonEight").click(function() {
        alert("foo");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.notice").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked me.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be changed to select based off the class (or an `id`). To select based off a CSS class, the syntax is **.classname** (note the dot before the name of the class).

To select an element with multiple classes, the syntax is **.classone.classtwo**.

In your case, you can use something like:

```
$('.buttonEight').click(function()
{
   //your awesome code goes here.
});
```